# Java - find the closest value(higher) in array list

Tags: java

Hi guys I am wondering if it is possible to find the closest value in an arraylist, which will return me the higher value.

Example: arraylist of [3,7,12,19] if my value is 8 how can I get the nearest(larger) value 12?

hi guys thanks for the reply, Im asking for the logic or understanding pls don't get it wrong that I am waiting for answer! I have tried with this function but what I wanted is to get the higher(larger) value which is closer. this just give me the closest but not the larger closest value

```
public int nearestValue(int value, ArrayList<Integer>List)
{
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = List.size()-1;
    int lastValue = 0;

    while(lo <= hi)
    {
        int mid = (lo + hi) /2;
        lastValue = List.get(mid);
        if (value < lastValue)
        {
            hi = mid - 1;
        }
        else if (value > lastValue)
        {
            lo = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return lastValue;
        }
    }
    return lastValue;
}
```

Comment: Look at `Arrays.binarySearch`

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have *you* tried?

Comment: Stack is not a resource, where you can ask to do your work. Try it yourself, put the code and write, whit is going wrong in it.

Comment: Here's a possible algorithm: Sort the `ArrayList` in descending order, scan the list until you find a value less than your number, then return the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Please add some code of your attempt before asking for help.

Here is some food for thought to get you started (if the array isn't sorted):

1) Iterate through the array

2) Check if the index you are looking at is higher than the value you are using

3) Calculate the difference between them and save it in a temporary variable.

4) Repeat

5) Check if difference of the new index you are looking at is smaller than the previous (temporary)

6) Save smallest difference

However, if the array is sorted, have a look at binary search and have a think about how you can use the above to make it more efficient.

Comment: Why are you saving a difference? There is nothing in the question asking for it.

Comment: This is how would check whether it is indeed, the closest 'highest value'. You want integer with the smallest difference.